# RuleUnitProvider.get() throws an error when called from a Spring Boot RequestController

Tags: java, spring-boot, drools, kogito

I have a spring-boot project that uses

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.drools</groupId>
            <artifactId>drools-ruleunits-engine</artifactId>
            <version>8.33.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

I have rules set up using a RuleUnit and everything works correctly when running basic Unit Tests. In my Unit Tests I use this line: `RuleUnitProvider.get().createRuleUnitInstance(requestAccessUnit);` to create a RuleUnitInstance and it works w/o issue.

However, when I try to instantiate the same RuleUnitInstance in my `@RequestController` I get the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot find any rule unit for RuleUnitData of class:yyyy.xxxx.zzzz.RuleUnit
```

The previous log statement shows `KieProject - No files found for KieBase defaultKieBase` which leads me to believe that it's not able to load the rule files into the KieBase.

Do I have to use the `kie-maven-plugin` and change my package to `kjar` in order for this to work? Is there a way to get this to work w/o using the `kjar` packaging? The way our build is set up makes it very problematic to use kjar.

I didn't see a lot [in the documentation](https://docs.drools.org/8.29.0.Final/drools-docs/docs-website/drools/KIE/index.html#_client_code) regarding using RuleUnits in Spring Boot so I am not sure how to proceed. I tried doing this in Kogito as well and ran into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For best integration of Drools with Spring Boot and per your StackOverflow question tags, you should consider using Kogito --and therefore using the Kogito API or [Kogito Incubation API](https://blog.kie.org/2021/09/kogito-api-incubation.html) (rather than just directly the Drools API).

Comment: I see, I didn't realize Spring Boot support was completely taken out of Drools and moved into Kogito. I'm still having trouble figuring out where that line of separation is. Does this mean Drools no longer has Spring Boot support natively?     

I started this project using Kogito and moved away b/c I was getting this error even when trying to run the rules in Unit Tests. I guess I'll try to go back to Kogito and see if I can resolve this issue there. 

Thank you again for your help!

Comment: No one said Drools does not support Spring Boot. What I've affirmed that using Kogito is typicall better suited for most projects and should be easier for new projects to onboard for Rules, Decision and Workflow, especially in a cloud-native setting such as Kubernetes.

Comment: I see. I only mentioned this because Spring was removed from the Drools documentation in version 8.